# Official images for Wandboard Quad

Tags: hardware, ubuntu-minimal

I would like to ask if there will be official images of Ubuntu 14.04 for [Wandboard Quad](http://wandboard.org/index.php/details).

Simply because I saw this [reference](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/main/installer-armhf/current/images/generic/netboot/wandboard-quad/) on http://ports.ubuntu.com/.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems that official images of Ubuntu 14.04 are not available yet. I'm trying with the Robert Nelson's tutorial to make a Ubuntu 14.04 image. I can access the console, but the x server fail to start and i don't know how to make the GUI appear. The typical

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Appears. So, for now the Ubuntu image do not work too well.